# Set a Default CPT taxonomy by taxonomy id

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, customization

How can I set a default CPT taxonomy by taxonomy id?
I don't want to do it by slug. Must be by ID.

Comment: And what do you mean by “set the default taxonomy”? And what is the taxonomy id? By saying “taxonomy” you mean “term” by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I could have been more clear. Let's say I have a CPT "reviews" and a "locations" taxonomy associated with it. I have 4 terms for locations. I want to set a default "location" term and I want to set it by id and not slug.